# When an E-R attribute should be perceived as a relationship attribute or as an entity set attribute?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

**Aspects worth to consider from the very beginning**:

- In order to maintain the degree of simplicity of the problem this post presents, I haven't provided the exact requirement, on the basis of the bellow E-R diagram was sketched;
- If the given information aren't satisfactory further details will be provided without hesitation;

Given the explanation book 1 delivers:

> 7.7.4 Placement of Relationship Attributes

> The cardinality ratio of a relationship can affect the placement of relationship
> attributes. Thus, attributes of one-to-one or one-to-many relationship sets can be
> associated with one of the participating entity sets, rather than with the relationship set..

1.Would you rather prefer to keep the attribute *start_date* as a relationship attribute or to englobe it in the entity set *Congress_Persons*?

2.Why?

[image]

**My answer**:
I tend to believe that in order to diminish any shadow of doubt that might appear when deciding what is the most representative place to which this attribute belongs, the *start_date* should be inextricably linked to *represents* relationship. This way it would explicitly express that the action of taking up a mandate will unarguably come with a start_date.

1 - Database System Concepts Henry F. Korth, S. Sudarshan, Abraham Silberschatz